# Loop through files in directory and zip

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script to loop through all files in a directory, and individually zip them to another directory.

Currently I have this:

```sh
FILES=/media/user/storage/unzipped/*
for f in $FILES
do
  7za a -t7z /media/user/storage/zipped/$f.7z $f -mx9 -r -ppassword -mhe
done
```

The problem is that the variable $f includes the absolute path to the source file, so my output file ends up in /media/user/storage/zipped/media/user/storage/unzipped/

How can I extract only the name from the $f variable?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I feel stupid not knowing about basename now!!

A few people have the same (correct) answer so I marked the oldest (and most detailed) one as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `basename` function:

```
FILES=/media/user/storage/unzipped/*
for f in $FILES
do
  7za a -t7z "/media/user/storage/zipped/$(basename $f).7z" $f -mx9 -r -ppassword -mhe
done
```

But, you may have problem with files in subfolders, so you can change the wordking directory:

```
#record current dir
OWD=$(pwd)  

# move to interesting directory 
cd /media/user/storage/unzipped

# zip
for f in *
do
  7za a -t7z /media/user/storage/zipped/$f.7z $f -mx9 -r -ppassword -mhe
done

# restore dir
cd $OWD
```

Comment: It will be better to add `fb=$(basename $f)` at the start of the loop and use $fb instead of $f

Answer (score 2):

You can use so called **Parameter expansion**, which I believe is a good use for you:

```
FILES=/media/user/storage/unzipped/*
for f in $FILES
do
  7za a -t7z /media/user/storage/zipped/${f##*/}.7z $f -mx9 -r -ppassword -mhe
done
```

More on Parameter Expansion - [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal)

Comment: Awesome! This has actually saved me asking another question about stripping the filename from the output of sha256sum :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to extract filename from the path:

```
FILES=/media/user/storage/unzipped/*
for f in $FILES
do
  filename=$(basename "$f")
  7za a -t7z /media/user/storage/zipped/${filename}.7z $f -mx9 -r -ppassword -mhe
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For recursively finding files in `/media/user/storage/unzipped/` you use nullglob

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in /media/user/storage/unzipped/** # See [1]
do
  [ -f "$f" ] &&  7za a -t7z "/media/user/storage/zipped/${f##*/}.7z" "$f" -mx9 -r -ppassword -mhe # See [2]
done
shopt -u nullglob
```

---

**References**

1. The `**` recursively finds anything under the given directory which may include directories as well, so in the next step check if `$f` is indeed a file (`[ -f "$f" ]`) and then zip it.
2. The `${f##*/}` gives you the basename of the file. See param [[ expansion ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).
3. Double quote the variables to prevent [[  word splitting ]](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

Comment: Fortunately I don't need to pick up directories, but I did end up needing nullglob, as otherwise if the directory is empty it tries to zip other things, thanks!